# Cant change Progressbar color from tkinter to red

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, progress-bar

I've seen some solutions to change the color of the Progressbar, however, when trying to apply them, it doesn't work and stays green.

I am probably missing a stupid thing.

This is a progressbar that is vertical, and it takes 10 seconds to fill. All I want is that the bar becomes red instead of green.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import time
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
seconds = 10
s = Style()
s.configure("red.Vertical.TProgressbar", foreground = 'red', background = 'red', throughcolor = 'red')
progress = Progressbar(root, orient = VERTICAL, length = 9999999, mode = 'determinate')
progress.configure(style = 'red.Vertical.TProgressbar')
progress.pack(ipadx = 200000, padx = 50, pady = 50) 
start_time = time.time()
elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time

while elapsed_time/seconds*100 < 100:
    progress['value'] = elapsed_time/seconds*100
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    root.update()
    time.sleep(0)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change ttk.progressBar color in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13510882/how-to-change-ttk-progressbar-color-in-python)

Comment: I tried that exact code without anything else and it still had a green bar

Comment: I don't believe you. When I run it in Python 3.8, the bar is red.

Comment: I think the problem was that I wasnt using the theme and instead was trying to copy paste only the lines that I 'thought' would work

Comment: So you didn't try the exact code without anything else.

Comment: Yea, sorry. I was blindsided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
import time
import tkinter  as tk
from  tkinter import  ttk
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
seconds = 10
s = ttk.Style()
s.theme_use('clam')
s.configure("red.Vertical.TProgressbar", foreground='red', background='red')
progress = ttk.Progressbar(root, style="red.Vertical.TProgressbar", orient="vertical", length=600, mode="determinate", maximum=4, value=1)
progress.pack(ipadx = 200000, padx = 50, pady = 50)

start_time = time.time()
elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time

while elapsed_time/seconds*100 < 100:
    progress['value'] = elapsed_time/seconds*100
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    root.update()
    time.sleep(0)
```

I have also green when have tried your variant.

Comment: It worked. The line missing was the `s.theme_use('clam')`